# .htaccessでPC＿URLからredirect SP

Tags: .htaccess

誰かお解る方がいましたらぜひご教授お願いいたします。

下記の場合は.htaccessを使用する場合どうしたらできますか？
http://xxxx.jp/book/vol1/#!6  ==>  http://xxxx.jp/sp/book/vol1/index.html#present

お願いいたします.

Answer (score 1):

※動作は未確認です

htaccessの詳細な設定方法は別途お調べ頂くとして、恒久的なリダイレクトは下記です。

```
Redirect permanent http://xxxx.jp/book/vol1/#!6 http://xxxx.jp/sp/book/vol1/index.html#present
```

一時的にリダイレクトする場合は`permanent`部を`temp`としてください。

Comment: なるほど、この書き方でできるんですね！！
ありがとうございます！！